# Gatsby and Directus: get referenced file from table row

Tags: gatsby, directus

I have a Directus instance that has a "users" table. Each user row has an image associated with it. I'm trying to use [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) to display each user's image on a profile page, but I'm having trouble associating each user with its image within Gatsby.

I'm using [gatsby-source-directus](https://github.com/iKonrad/gatsby-source-directus) and Gatsby v2. I have no problem getting a list of all my users using this GraphQL query:

```
{
    allDirectusUser {
        edges {
            node {
                firstName,
                lastName,
                username,
                gender
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I add the image to the GraphQL query, these are the (useful) fields I can query:

```
{
    allDirectusUser {
        edges {
            node {
                firstName,
                lastName,
                username,
                gender,
                image {
                    data {
                        name,
                        url
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output
{
    "data": {
        "allDirectusUser": {
            "edges": [{
                "node": {
                    "firstName": "jk",
                    "lastName": "joshing",
                    "username": "jkjustjoshing",
                    "gender": "m",
                    "image": {
                        "data": {
                            "name": "9e34b416be5e81aca5e1806662f555af.jpg",
                            "url": "/storage/uploads/9e34b416be5e81aca5e1806662f555af.jpg"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping the image name or URL would correspond to the ID assigned to the file in the `allFiles` GraphQL list, but it appears that the IDs are completely different and unrelated:

```
{
    allFiles {
        edges {
            node {
                absolutePath,
                base,
                name,
                publicURL,
                id
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output
{
    "data": {
        "allFiles": {
            "edges": [{
                "node": {
                    "absolutePath": "/Users/jkjustjoshing/Documents/gatsbyProject/.cache/gatsby-source-filesystem/dc43c94c4bcc309ba39fc0e723ef14af.jpg",
                    "base": "dc43c94c4bcc309ba39fc0e723ef14af.jpg",
                    "name": "dc43c94c4bcc309ba39fc0e723ef14af",
                    "publicURL": "/static/dc43c94c4bcc309ba39fc0e723ef14af-adecf30d9a17f3d98651e7476178da68.jpg",
                    "id": "6ede8075-f33e-5273-8dcd-8d41f3b365f5"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

The ID that Directus knows is `9e34b...`, and the ID that Gatsby knows is `dc43c...`. It seems that the Gatsby ID is being created when `gatsby-source-directus` downloads the image from my Directus server. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if the plugin isn't working correctly.

I'm hoping someone can helpe me either a) get these to match, or b) query the image's `publicURL` directly off the user object, instead of making a 2nd image query and trying to filter the images.